# Walk the control tree in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Given the following XAML:

```
<ListView Name="UnitProperties" Grid.Column="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When the TextBox loses focus, I want to get the value of the label in the first column. How do I do this via code? The Parent property of the textbox is null.

Comment: TRY: Setting a Property [((MyRowVM)textBox.DataContext).HasFocus = false] from the TextBox_LostFocus_1 handler. In the setter for MyRowVM.HasFocus, this.Name should give you the right Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TextBox_LostFocus handler, you can get the value of Name property like this -

```
var dataContext = (sender as TextBox).DataContext;
string labelContent = dataContext.Name;
```